# i got this array from laravel controller now how to print this in laravel blade. because here is an array and inside this there is another array

Tags: laravel

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990027 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:42:54) 
 [1] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990042 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T12:51:53.483 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990043 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T12:51:53.51 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990060 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T12:56:11 )
 [4] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990101 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:05:57 ) 
 [5] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990102 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:08:42 ) 
 [6] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990109 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:05:12 ) 
 [7] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990115 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:07:54 ) 
 [8] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990116 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:05:31 ) 
 [9] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990117 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:04:59 ) 
 [10] => Array ( [JobId] => 5990118 [DeliveryDate] => 2018-07-18T13:07:18 ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to read up on loops in Blade templates.  Here's the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops).  Perhaps foreach will do what you want, then just loop through them and follow the examples to see how you can reference that particular element as output.